# use join in three table but result show in many rows

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

i have three table OccupancyType, RoomType and Hotel_MealPlan. data is:-

OccupancyType Data:-

```
Hotel_ID    Name
       1    Double
       1    single
     680    Double
     680    single
```

Hotel_MealPlan

```
Hotel_ID    Meal_Plan   rate
       1    CP          0
       1    MAP         500
     680    CP          400
     680    EP          400         
       1    EP          200
```

RoomType

```
Hotel_ID    Name    Rate    Season    StartSeason   EndSeason
 680    Deluxe/Ac   2300    Diwali   2013-11-01 2013-11-15
 680    Deluxe/Ac   1000    Normal    NULL          NULL
   1    Deluxe/Ac   2700    Diwali    2013-11-01    2013-11-15
   1    Deluxe/Ac   1200    Normal    NULL          NULL
   1    Deluxe/Ac   2500    New Year  2013-12-20    2014-01-10
   1    Deluxe/Ac   3800    31 Dec    2013-12-31    2013-12-31
```

I want when i select hotel_Id '1', occupancyType Name='Double', Meal_Plan = 'MAP' and my roomtype name='Deluxe/Ac' and date between startSeason and EndSeason or if start end season Null then pick null rate. i want result like:- below

```
Name    Name    Rate    startseason endseason   Meal_Plan   rate
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL        MAP         500
```

my query is

```
select o.Name,r.Name,r.Rate,r.startseason, r.endseason, m.Meal_Plan,m.rate 
from OccupancyType o 
inner join RoomType r on o.Hotel_ID = r.Hotel_ID 
inner join Hotel_MealPlan m on m.Hotel_ID = o.Hotel_ID 
where r.Hotel_ID = '1' 
and r.Name = 'Deluxe/Ac' 
and o.Name = 'Double' 
and m.Meal_Plan = 'MAP' 
and '2013-09-09' between r.startseason and r.endseason 
or r.startseason is null 
and r.endseason is null
```

my result is:-

```
Name    Name    Rate    startseason endseason   Meal_Plan   rate
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    CP          0
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    MAP         500
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    EP          200
single  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    CP          0
single  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    MAP         500
single  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    EP          200
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    CP          0
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    MAP         600
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    CP          400
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    EP          400
Double  Deluxe/Ac   1200    NULL    NULL    MAP         600 ........
```

48 rows show on my result... what i m missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join is showing you all rows that match either:

```
r.Hotel_ID = '1' 
and r.Name = 'Deluxe/Ac' 
and o.Name = 'Double' 
and m.Meal_Plan = 'MAP' 
and '2013-09-09' between r.startseason and r.endseason
```

or

```
r.startseason is null 
and r.endseason is null
```

You possibly want to do something like:

```
WHERE r.Hotel_ID = '1' 
AND r.Name = 'Deluxe/Ac' 
AND o.Name = 'Double' 
AND m.Meal_Plan = 'MAP' 
AND ('2013-09-09' between r.startseason and r.endseason 
    OR (r.startseason is null 
    AND r.endseason is null))
```

This will still always bring back the off season rate, if there is a season rate, but you could also add some ordering and only use the first row (etc.)

Comment: it's working but  if i choose any date like '2013-11-11' . then it's show both condition null value and date between then it's show two row. if i choose  '2013-12-31' then it's show three row null , date between 2013-12-20  to  2014-01-10 and 2013-12-31  to  2013-12-31. if i chose 2013-12-31 then i want rate from mealplan 3800 show please help me

Comment: Hence why I mentioned that you should apply an order of applicability, and only use the most applicable value. Better still would be to define start/end dates always (even if a long way in the future)

Comment: i also try:-  select top 1 ........ AND ('2013-09-09' between r.startseason and r.endseason OR (r.startseason is null AND r.endseason is null)) order by case when r.startseason is null and r.endseason is null then 2 else 1 end.   But in this query rate pick 2500

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
select o.Name,r.Name,r.Rate,r.startseason, r.endseason, m.Meal_Plan,
```

rate =CASE WHEN r.startseason =NULL THEN NULL 
             WHEN r.endseason =NULL THEN NULLL
             ELSE m.rate END
from OccupancyType o 
inner join RoomType r on o.Hotel_ID = r.Hotel_ID and r.Name = 'Deluxe/Ac' and o.Name = 'Double' 
inner join Hotel_MealPlan m on m.Hotel_ID = o.Hotel_ID and m.Meal_Plan = 'MAP' 
where r.Hotel_ID = '1' 
and (('2013-09-09' between r.startseason and r.endseason) or 
or r.startseason is null 
or r.endseason is null )

Comment: it's working but if i choose any date like '2013-11-11' or '2013-12-31'. it's pick rate only where startseason and endseason is null

Comment: @Shiv : Updated the answer. Might be this will help you